# Ansible - use delegate_to and access environment variable from delegated host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I'm trying to look for a text pattern in a load balancer host from a worker host, using the following:

```
- name: A play
  hosts: workers
  tasks:
    - name: Look for text pattern in delegated host
      delegate_to: load-balancer-host
      find:
        paths: "$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE/subdir"
        file_type: file
        patterns: file.pattern
        contains: 'text pattern'
      register: aVariable
```

The problem is that I can't found any way to make $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE (this variable exists in the load-balancer-host) available for the play (it contains the directory, in load-balancer-host, from where I want to look for). ansible_env is only available for the workers but not for the load-balancer-host

I have tried...

```
- name: A play
  hosts: workers
  tasks:
    - name: set fact
      set_fact:
        env_var: "{{ lookup('env', 'ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE') }}"
      delegate_to: load-balancer-host

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ env_var }}"
```

... too, but it prints an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users running Ansible 1.x, see kfreezy's answer.

For users running Ansible 2.x, I have found the following solution:

```
- hosts: workers
  tasks:
    - name: gather facts from lb
      setup:
      delegate_to: load-balancer-host
      delegate_facts: false
```

This task will make $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE available in every worker *ansible_env* var. If you want to make $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE available in the load-balancer-host *ansible_env*, just set *delegate_facts* to True.

More info in [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would simplify your playbook by either adding the `$ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` as a variable in Ansible (probably in the `host_vars` for load-balancer-host) or running a play against load-balancer-host rather than use `delegate_to`. It might not make sense depending on what the other tasks are.

Here's a direct answer to your question though.

load-balancer-host's `ansible_env` will only be defined when the host is included in the playbook.  You can add another play against the 'load-balancer-host' that will just gather facts. Then you can reference the facts from 'load-balancer-host' using `hostvars` in your subsequent plays against 'workers'.  He's what it would look like.

```
- hosts: load-balancer-host
  tasks:
  - name: print debug message
    debug:
      msg: "this play is for gathering facts on the LB"

- name: A play
  hosts: workers
  tasks:
  - name: Look for text pattern in delegated host
    delegate_to: load-balancer-host
    find:
      paths: "{{ hostvars['load-balancer-host'].ansible_env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE }}/subdir"
      file_type: file
      patterns: file.pattern
      contains: 'text pattern'
    register: aVariable
```

Comment: I think this is the only way to go in Ansible 1.x. I have proposed another way for Ansible 2.x users.